# Spyder Ide in python does not launch after I did some updates

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

My laptop is running on a Linux Ubuntu 16 version.

After typing  spyder3 in terminal this is the error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 2331, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 2215, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 752, in setup
    from spyderlib.plugins.inspector import ObjectInspector
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/plugins/inspector.py", line 41, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.ipython import IPythonControlWidget
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/ipython.py", line 28, in <module>
    pygments_patch.apply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/pygments_patch.py", line 22, in apply
    from pygments.lexer import _TokenType, Text, Error
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pygments/lexer.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pygments.filters import get_filter_by_name
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pygments/filters/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pygments.plugin import find_plugin_filters
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pygments/plugin.py", line 39, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

How should I deal with this error ?
When I try to open it from the icon it says in from the last time it happened an error and that I should reset the Spyder. I checked earlier stuffs in the internet but none of them worked.Please can anyone help me ?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't know what's causing your error, but from your traceback it's clear that the Spyder version you're trying to use is about three years old, and (at this point) unsupported by us. So you'd be much better by downloading and installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux) which comes with the latest version of Spyder and all its dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! Installing Anaconda was a really right choice!

Comment: Great!! Glad to know you found my suggestion useful.